# Hide tooltip if already added to homescreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios

I'm using [this plugin](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) to show a tooltip for adding the website to homescreen, but once added, I don't want the tooltip to appear again. The doc says I should just add a meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

I did but I still see the tooltip every time. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable autostart of the plugin by setting the `addToHomeConfig` before including the plugin's JS file.

```
var addToHomeConfig = {
    autostart : false
    //add your other options here
};
//use script tag to include the plugin.
```

Then, detect if the app is running in "Web App Mode" by inserting the code below

```
if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone){
    //show fullscreen tooltip
    addToHome.show();  //this shows the tooltip
}
```